# How to query items and orders them if one of params is in the list

Tags: django, orm

I've got the list with users:

```
following = [x.user for x in UserFollow.objects.filter(user=request.user)]
```

Also the tweets:

```
tweets = Tweet.objects.all()
```

How can i sort the tweets to have tweets that are created by users in `following`
at first places?

Models:

```
class UserFollow(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="following")
    follower = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="followers")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Tweet(models.Model): 
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=1024)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="tweet_likes", blank=True, through=TweetLike)
    comments = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="tweet_comments", blank=True, through=TweetComment)
    image = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: [Edit] and add the relevant models to your question...

Answer (score 0):

Django filters have a [in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#in) clause so you can imitate queries like this one:

```
SELECT * WHERE user IN following`
```

So a possible solution might look like:

```py
tweets_following = Tweet.objects.filter(user__in = following)
```

Comment: The case is, that i would like to have the tweets with users that i follow at first, and then the rest of them.

Comment: @Kubens95 The you can use the exclude function in the same way to have a list with the rest of the tweets, thus getting a list of the tweets of people you follow, and a list of tweets of people you dont follow.